# How to Add Html Content To Popup Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am  using Magiczoomplus gallery plugin to show image slider in bigger  size as popup window. it works great. Now the problem is i want to add html content to popup window. How can i do for this?

Here is Code:

```css
figure.mz-figure {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 !important;
    -webkit-perspective: 300px;
            perspective: 300px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.MagicZoom img,
.mz-figure img {
    border: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    outline: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.MagicZoom > img,
.mz-figure > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.ie8-magic .MagicZoom > img,
.ie8-magic .mz-figure > img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none !important;
}
.mz-figure.mz-no-zoom.mz-no-expand,
.mz-expand .mz-figure.mz-no-zoom {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.mz-figure.mz-active,
.mz-expand {
    -ms-touch-action: none;
        touch-action: none;
}

.mz-lens,
.mz-zoom-window {
    position: absolute !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    pointer-events: none !important;
}
.mz-lens img,
.mz-zoom-window img {
    position: absolute !important;
    max-width: none !important;
    max-height: none !important;
}
.mz-lens img {
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
            transition: none !important;
}

.mz-zoom-window {
    z-index: 2000000000;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
            transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
.mz-zoom-window.mz-magnifier {
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, white, black);
    -webkit-mask-clip: content;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.mz-figure.mz-active .mz-zoom-window.mz-magnifier {
    pointer-events: auto !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
.mz-zoom-window.mz-magnifier.mz-expanded {
    z-index: 2147483647;
}
.mz-zoom-window img  {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    left: -1000%;
    right: -1000%;
    top: -1000%;
    bottom: -1000%;
    margin: auto !important;
    -webkit-transition: none;
            transition: none;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% !important;
        -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50% !important;
            transform-origin: 50% 50% !important;
}
.mz-zoom-window.mz-preview img {
    top: 0 !important;
    bottom: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    -webkit-transform: none !important;
            transform: none !important;
}
.lt-ie9-magic .mz-zoom-window img  {
    margin: 0 !important;
}

.mz-expand-controls {
    z-index: 2147483647;
}

.mz-fade {
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s;
            transition: opacity .25s;
}
.mz-hidden {
    opacity: 0;
}
.mz-visible {
    opacity: 1;
}

.mobile-magic .mz-expand .mz-expand-bg {
    -webkit-transform-style: flat !important;
            transform-style: flat !important;
}
.mobile-magic .mz-expand .mz-image-stage > figure .mz-caption {
    display: none !important;
}
.mobile-magic .mz-expand-controls.mz-fade {
    transition: none !important;
}
.mobile-magic .mz-expand > .mz-zoom-window {
    top: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
}

.mz-expanded-view-open,
.mz-expanded-view-open body {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
.mz-expanded-view-open body { height: auto !important; }


/**
 * Main figure
 */
.mz-figure.mz-active {
   display:none !important;
}
.mz-figure.mz-no-zoom,
.mz-figure.mz-click-zoom,
.mz-figure.mz-active {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.mz-figure.mz-active.mz-magnifier-zoom.mz-hover-zoom.mz-no-expand {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.mz-figure.mz-magnifier-zoom.mz-active {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
.mz-zoom-window {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.mz-zoom-window.mz-magnifier {
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 0;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
}
.mz-zoom-window.mz-magnifier:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;bottom: 0;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 1px solid rgba(170,170,170,0.7);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    background: transparent;
    z-index: 1;
}
.mz-zoom-window.mz-magnifier.mz-square,
.mz-zoom-window.mz-magnifier.mz-square:before {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}
.lt-ie9-magic .mz-zoom-window {
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.mz-zoom-window.mz-inner {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

/* Caption in zoom window */
.mz-zoom-window .mz-caption {
    background: #777;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 10pt;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 150;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: normal !important;
    text-align: center !important;
}
.lt-ie9-magic .mz-zoom-window .mz-caption {
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
.mz-zoom-window.caption-bottom .mz-caption {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
}
.mz-zoom-window.mz-expanded > .mz-caption {
    display: none;
}

/* Zoom window animations */
.mz-zoom-window.mz-deactivating,
.mz-zoom-window.mz-activating {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.9), -webkit-transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.9);
            transition: opacity 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.9), transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.9);
}
.mz-zoom-window.mz-deactivating {
    -webkit-transition-duration: .25s, .25s, .25s;
            transition-duration: .25s, .25s, .25s;
}
.mz-zoom-window.mz-p-right,
.mz-zoom-window.mz-p-left,
.mz-zoom-window.mz-p-top,
.mz-zoom-window.mz-p-bottom {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -100;
}
.mz-zoom-window.mz-p-right {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-20%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-20%, 0, 0);
}
.mz-zoom-window.mz-p-left {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(20%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(20%, 0, 0);
}
.mz-zoom-window.mz-p-top {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 20%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 20%, 0);
}
.mz-zoom-window.mz-p-bottom {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -20%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, -20%, 0);
}
/* Inner mode animation */
.mz-zoom-window > img {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.mz-zoom-window.mz-p-inner.mz-deactivating > img,
.mz-zoom-window.mz-p-inner.mz-activating > img {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .22s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.9);
            transition: transform .22s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.9);
}
/* Magnifier mode animation */
.mz-zoom-window.mz-p-magnifier {
    -webkit-transform: scale(.1);
            transform: scale(.1);
}
/* Preview mode animation */
.mz-zoom-window.mz-preview.mz-deactivating,
.mz-zoom-window.mz-preview.mz-activating,
.mz-zoom-window.mz-custom.mz-deactivating,
.mz-zoom-window.mz-custom.mz-activating {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.9);
            transition: opacity 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.9);
}
.mz-zoom-window.mz-preview.mz-deactivating,
.mz-zoom-window.mz-custom.mz-deactivating {
    -webkit-transition-duration: .2s;
            transition-duration: .2s;
}
.mz-zoom-window.mz-p-preview,
.mz-zoom-window.mz-p-custom {
    opacity: 0;
}


/**
 * Hint & Loading
 */
.mz-hint,
.mz-loading {
    color: #eee;
    background: red;
    font: normal 12px/1.2em 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Verdana, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    direction: ltr;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease;
    transition: opacity 0.25s ease;
}

.mobile-magic .mz-hint-message:before {
    display: none;
}

.mz-hint-hidden {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transition-delay: .6s;
            transition-delay: .6s;
}
/* Hint in the expanded view on mobile */
.mz-expand .mz-hint {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.1em;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: auto;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(0,-50%);
            transform: translate(0,-50%);

}
.mz-expand .mz-hint-message {
    padding: 1.1em;
}
.mz-expand .mz-hint-message:before {
    display: none;
}
.mz-expand .mz-hint-hidden {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
            transition-delay: 1s;
    opacity: 0;
}

/* Loading indicator */
.mz-loading {
    font-size: 0;
    border-radius: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.mz-loading:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    margin: auto;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    border-top-color: transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.mz-loading.shown {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0s;
    transition: opacity 0s;
}
.mz-loading.shown:after {
    -webkit-animation: spin-loading .9s infinite linear;
            animation: spin-loading .9s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin-loading {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
                transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
                transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes spin-loading {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
                transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
                transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

.lt-ie10-magic .mz-loading {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: .7em 1.1em;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
.lt-ie10-magic .mz-loading:after {
    content: 'Loading...';
    text-indent: 0;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
}

.lt-ie9-magic .mz-loading {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    right: 0;
    left:  0;
    width: 126px;
    margin: auto;
}
.lt-ie9-magic .mz-hint-message,
.lt-ie9-magic .mz-loading.shown {
    background: transparent !important;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr='#7c31333D', EndColorStr='#7c31333D');
}
.lt-ie9-magic .mz-hint-hidden {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}



/**
 * Expanded view
 */
.mz-expand,
.mz-expand .mz-expand-bg,
.mz-expand .mz-expand-bg > img,
.mz-expand .mz-expand-bg > svg,
.mz-expand .mz-expand-stage,
.mz-expand .mz-expand-stage .mz-image-stage {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    left: 0; right: 0;
}
.mz-expand .mz-expand-bg,
.mz-expand .mz-expand-bg > img,
.mz-expand .mz-expand-bg > svg {
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;

}
.mz-expand .mz-expand-bg,
.mz-expand .mz-expand-bg > svg  {
    min-width: 100% !important;
    min-height: 100% !important;
}

.mz-expand {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 2100000000;
    position: fixed;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-perspective: 600px;
            perspective: 600px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

/* Expanded view background */
.mz-expand .mz-expand-bg {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    max-width: none !important;
    max-height: none !important;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0) scale(10) rotate(0.01deg);
        -ms-transform: translate(0,0) scale(10,10) rotate(0.01deg);
            transform: translate3d(0,0,0) scale(10) rotate(0.01deg);
    -webkit-perspective: 600px;
            perspective: 600px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.mz-expand .mz-expand-bg > img  {
    margin: auto;
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'blur\'><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation=\'80\' in=\'SourceGraphic\'></feGaussianBlur></filter></svg>#blur");
    -webkit-filter: blur(20px) brightness(60%);
            filter: blur(20px) brightness(60%);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
            transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.mz-expand .mz-expand-bg > svg  {
    margin: auto;
    opacity: .6;
}

[data-magic-ua=edge] .mz-expand .mz-expand-bg,
.lt-ie10-magic .mz-expand .mz-expand-bg {
    display: none !important;
}
.lt-ie9-magic .mz-expand {
    background: #1f1f1f;
}
[data-magic-ua=edge] .mz-expand {
    background-color: rgba(31, 31, 31, .96);
}

/** Plain backgrounds: dark-bg, white-bg **/
.mz-expand.plain-bg .mz-expand-bg,
.mz-expand.dark-bg .mz-expand-bg,
.mz-expand.white-bg .mz-expand-bg {
    display: none !important;
}
.mz-expand.dark-bg {
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    background-color: rgba(31, 31, 31, .96);
}
.mz-expand.white-bg {
    background-color: #fff;
}

/* Expanded view stage */
.mz-expand .mz-expand-stage {
    z-index: 2100000000;
    padding: 0;
}
.mz-expand .mz-expand-stage .mz-image-stage {
    z-index: 50;
    left: 120px;
    right: 120px;
    padding: 20px 0 40px 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-perspective: 600px;
            perspective: 600px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.mz-expand .mz-expand-stage.with-thumbs .mz-image-stage {
    padding-bottom: 120px;
}
.mz-expand .mz-expand-stage.mz-zoom-in .mz-image-stage {
    padding: 0 !important;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.mz-expand .mz-image-stage > figure:before,
.mz-expand .mz-image-stage:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 100%;
    width: 0;
}
.mz-expand .mz-image-stage > figure {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.mz-expand .mz-figure {
    overflow: visible;
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
.mz-expand .mz-figure > img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
.mz-expand .mz-zoom-in .mz-image-stage > figure,
.mz-expand .mz-zoom-in .mz-image-stage > figure .mz-figure.mz-activating,
.mz-expand .mz-zoom-in .mz-image-stage > figure .mz-figure.mz-active {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.mz-expand .mz-figure {
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: -webkit-zoom-in;
    cursor: -moz-zoom-in;
    cursor: zoom-in;
}

/* When inner zoom is always shown */
.mz-expand .mz-expand-stage.mz-zoom-in.mz-always-zoom .mz-image-stage > figure > figure > img {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: -5000px !important;
    bottom: -5000px !important;
    left: -5000px !important;
    right: -5000px !important;
    margin: auto !important;
}

.lt-ie10-magic .mz-zoom-window.mz-expanded img  { filter: alpha(opacity=100); }
.lt-ie10-magic .mz-expand .mz-figure.mz-magnifier-zoom {
    overflow: hidden;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}


/* Caption in expanded view */
.mz-expand .mz-caption {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 46px #000;
    padding: 10px 4px;
    font: normal 10pt/1em 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Verdana, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
.mz-expand .mz-caption.mz-show {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.15s ease-out;
    transition: opacity 0.15s ease-out;
    opacity: 1;
}
.mz-expand .mz-caption a {
    color: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.mz-expand.white-bg .mz-caption {
    color: #555;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.lt-ie9-magic .mz-expand .mz-caption {
    top: 100%;
}

.mz-expand .mz-zoom-window {
    box-shadow: none;
    background: transparent;
}
.lt-ie9-magic .mz-expand .mz-zoom-window {
    border: 0;
}

/* Expanded view on mobile */
.mobile-magic .mz-expand-stage .mz-expand-thumbnails,
.mobile-magic .mz-expand-stage .mz-image-stage {
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
.mobile-magic .mz-expand .mz-expand-stage.with-thumbs {
    bottom: 0px;
}
.mobile-magic .mz-expand-stage .mz-image-stage {
    padding: 0;
}
.mobile-magic .mz-expand .mz-expand-stage.with-thumbs .mz-image-stage {
    padding: 5px 0 60px;
}
.mobile-magic .mz-expand .mz-expand-stage.mz-zoom-in .mz-image-stage {
    padding-top: 0;
}
.mobile-magic .mz-expand .mz-expand-thumbnails {
    padding: 0;
    height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="http://cms.seller.ir/js/magiczoomplus.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li><!-- Begin magiczoomplus -->
<a id="MagicZoomPlusImage177" class="MagicZoom" title="This is popup Window" data-zoom-image="http://jj-bg.info/gallery/album_1/min/test.png" data-options="zoomPosition:left;rightClick:true;cssClass:white-bg;" >
<img itemprop="image" src="http://jj-bg.info/gallery/album_1/min/test.png"  srcset="images/pic5.png 2x" />
</a>   
</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: html content means a new whole html page?

Comment: @JeetDaloneboy no. i just want to add 3 div  in html that shows in popup  window.

Comment: Ask this to magiczoomplus support, may be they'll help you.

Comment: When The Popup Is Occured

Comment: I Mean On Loading Time Or After Any Button Action

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't see the point of using text in this plugin, but I guess you have ideas about it. I see the plugin has hint settings, which shows text - you can try duplicate CSS and JavaScript from this setting.